# Delete rows if partial string not found in variety of columns: VBA

Tags: excel, vba, multiple-columns, delete-row

I'm trying to create a macro that will delete rows that do not contain the partial string ".csv" in any of the cells in that row. That caveat is that the string will not appear in the same column(s).

The following code works if the ".csv" explicit is found in column B:
(I need partial string search & across many columns)

```
    Sub DeleteRows()
' Defines variables
Dim Cell As Range, cRange As Range, LastRow As Long, x As Long


' Defines LastRow as the last row of data based on column E
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row


' Sets check range as E1 to the last row of E
Set cRange = Range("B1:B" & LastRow)


' For each cell in the check range, working from the bottom upwards
For x = cRange.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
    With cRange.Cells(x)
        ' If the cell does not contain one of the listed values then...
        If .Value <> ".csv" Then
        'And .Value <> "PENDING" And .Value <> "CANCELLED" Add to line above if you want to add specifications'
            ' Delete that row
            .EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    End With
' Check next cell, working upwards
Next x


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This adaptation of the posted code uses `COUNTIF` to search entire rows for any partial matches to `.csv`, if none are found the entire row is deleted.

It can be adapted to only delete only part of the row if required but more information would be needed for that.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteRows()
' Define variables
Dim Cell As Range, cRange As Range, LastRow As Long, x As Long
Dim Res As Variant

    ' Define LastRow as the last row of data based on column E
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    ' Sets check range as E1 to the last row of E
    Set cRange = Range("B1:B" & LastRow)

    ' For each cell in the check range, working from the bottom upwards
    For x = cRange.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
        ' find if '.csv' found in any cell in the row
        Res = Evaluate("COUNTIF(" & x & ":" & x & ", ""*.csv*"")")
        
        ' if '.csv' not found delete row
        If Res = 0 Then
            ActiveSheet.Rows(x).Delete
        End If
        
    Next x

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use InStr() for a partial search and add an inner for loop to go through each cell(column). If you hit a row you want to delete then use "exit for" right after you delete the row. That will exit the inner for loop and continue up to the next row.

Answer (score 0):

This code would search for all rows not containing atleast one ".csv" string and delete entire row.

```
Sub SearchForCSVRowsAndDeleteThem()
    Dim CSVLocation As Range, LastCellOfRow As Range, counter As Long, Lastrow As Long, sh As Worksheet
    Lastrow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Find Last row
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    For counter = Lastrow To 2 Step -1
        Set LastCellOfRow = sh.Range("XFD" & counter) 'Start searching after last cell of row
        Set CSVLocation = sh.Range(counter & ":" & counter). _
        Find(".csv", after:=LastCellOfRow, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart, searchorder:=xlByColumns, searchdirection:=xlNext) 'Search in each row
        If CSVLocation Is Nothing Then
            sh.cells(counter,1).EntireRow.Delete 'Delete Row if .csv is not found
        End If
    Next counter
    End Sub
```

Comment: for some reason it does not work for me. Seems to be due to the CSVLocation.EntireRow.Delete part (I did shift left the end sub)

Comment: Hello JMatthewByU this would work now. It was my silly mistake i originally made this code delete .csv rows and changed it at last moment of an error crept in.